# Why there is Untouchability in Hindu religion?

Tags: rituals, tradition, untouchability

I have sees from my childhood my mother always force us to do following activities

- After Nature Call you have to  take bath  up to waist or change the cloth for later cleaning.
- I somebody dies in your vansh and any baby born you have to change the janeu.
- If a girl is in Mensuration period, then she will sleeping on mat which should not be touched by anybody. She will alienated for three days.
- No low caste people should be allowed to cook your food or do your household activities.
- In india Thread ceremony has been differently performed in different places and it is very difficult to find the same pandit from your state to do the thread 
  change for you during **Mitrika**( During Child birth) and **Chhutrika**( If somebody dies in your vansh).

Please tell me how many of the above are justified or not.

I have seen many relatives who are matric fail, but still gives boastful statement of they are brahmin. Don't you think they should be demoted from brahmin to some other caste? Those who can't protect Vedant knowledge or pass through the correct knowledge to next generation should not be regarded as brahmin. Their brahmin license should be canceled.
Some authority should be there who should  keep track all the varna management

Please suggest a correct procedure for my question.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20504/discussion-on-question-by-brajabasi-padhy-why-there-is-untouchability-in-hindu-r).

Comment: 1. All of the above are practised and have justification 2. It is true that brahmins who do not follow their varnasrama dharmas are brahmins in name only and not true bhU-suras.3.Sankaracharya established 4 peethas in the 4 corners of India to preserve and propogate dharma. So, spiritual leaders (of any Hindu persuasion- Smarta, Vaishnava etc.) are the authority in dharma management matters. They propogate dharma through sattvic methods. It is up to us to seek their counsel and respect their teachings.